# Autoheight iFrame Safari Bug

Tags: jquery, iframe, safari, resize, height

I use jquery to auto resize the height of the iframe based on the content. It works perfect in Firefox but in Safari it gives me always the wrong height (150px).

Any solution?

```
function resizeIframe(obj){
     {obj.style.height = 0;};
     {obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using offset height:

```
function resizeIframe(obj){
     {obj.style.height = 0;};
     {obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';}
  }
```

**OR**

```
function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + "px";
}
```

Comment: If this is useful, please accept as answer. Otherwise let me know the issue with this solution.

Comment: Thank you for the try. With the first solution I see no iframe (Firefox + Safari). With the 2. function the same error as in Safari (wrong hight of 150px).

Comment: this is the Link: http://www.cahiers.de/wp/?page_id=21 (click on an article like Andreas Till VISUAL HAIKU)